# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…) in angular2

Tags: angular

this is the error saying ***" cannot read property 'push' of undefined "*** when using the code below

```
  let deal = new Deal(  5, 'afaf', 'dafa',5,23 ) 
  this.publicDeals.push( deal )   // gives a error saying Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)
```

The whole is shown below

```
export class Deal { 
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public  description: string,
    public originalPrice: number,
    public salePrice: number
      ) { }    
}
```

In another component,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Deal } from '../deal';
import { DealService } from '../deal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'public-deals',
  templateUrl: 'public-deals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['public-deals.component.css']
})

export class PublicDealsComponent implements OnInit {
  publicDeals: Deal[];

  constructor(
    private dealService: DealService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {    
      let deal = new Deal(  5, 'afaf', 'dafa',5,23 ) 
      this.publicDeals.push( deal )   // gives a error saying Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)

  }

  purchase(item){
    alert("You bought the: " + item.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

`publicDeals` is not initiated;

```
publicDeals: Deal[] = [];
```

Comment: Worked for the Angular 7

Comment: ...and useful for Angular 8 too. Thanks.

Comment: Works with Angular 9 too. Waiting for the guy who tries it with Angular 10

Comment: M the one who tried with Angular 10,  It's working over here, Great

Comment: It doesn't have anything to with Angular 2,3,4....Angular 12. There was a syntax error. It will work fine for every version of Angular, until and unless Angular changes its syntax for Array.

Comment: Ladies and gents... I can reassure you that it also works with Angular 14!

Answer (score 14):

you have to initialize array using below:

```
publicDeals: Deal[] = [];
```

or

```
publicDeals: Deal[] = new Array();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here goes the number array:

```
items : number[ ] = [ ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below approach for when you are adding the element into the array. the below code will work for all angular versions.

```
const publicDeals: Deal[] = []; //initialize the array
publicDeals.push(deal);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use AngularFire5.0
Before pushing you must list your items

```
const afList = afDb.list('items');
afList.push({ name: 'item' });
```

you should see the update of Angularfire 5.0 [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md)

Answer (score 1):

Works with

```
publicDeals: Deal[] = [];
```

I had the same issue before with the initialization

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was I wasn't declaring the array correctly. It was

```
optionsArray:any[];
```

It should be

```
optionsArayy:any=[];//(missing equal to)
```

Note: This creates an empty Array of type "any"