# cannot loop and assign api values in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a export type as below:

```
export type Program{
key: string; value: string;
}
```

I have array values returning from api as below:

```
apival = ["abc", "xyz" ...etc]
```

In my component I am doing this in my constructor

```
program: Program[];

constructor(private service: Service){
getval = service.apival;
getval.forEach((a) => {
program.push({
key: a, 
value: ""
})})}
```

Now I want to assign the returned array values as key to the program type. I am doing this with a forEach loop. But, I am getting the following error:

```
"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"
```

***Note:I tried to do this in service itself, but I am getting this error : "Cannot Instantiate cyclic dependency"***

Any idea, why this happens and what is the best way to assign the getval to the programs[]. Either in service or component.

***I dont want to do it on OnInit()***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…) in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291187/cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `program: Program[];` needs to be initialized like this `program: Array<Program> = new Array<Program>()`. Also you could use a `map` and get a new array.

```
this.program = getval.map(a=>{return {key:a, value:""}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
program: Program[] = [];
```

Since `program` is a class variable, you need to use it with `this` keyword (`this.program`).

One line solution with ES6 would be:

```
this.program = this.service.getval.map(a => {key: a, value: ""});
```

`map` will iterate through your given array and returns a new array.