# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11, angular12

When I call my function is throwing an error. I'm trying to insert my items via a forEach in angular. Below is the code which I tried.

[image: Console Error Logs]

**Ts code**

```
sItems: SaleProduct[];

btnSale() {

let tsale = new SaleProduct();

let tcustomerId = this.postForm.get('customer').value;

console.log(this.items);

this.items.forEach(obj => {
  tsale.CustomerId = tcustomerId;
  tsale.ProductId = obj.Id;
  tsale.CostPrice = obj.CostPrice;
  tsale.SellingPrice = obj.SellingPrice;

  console.log(tsale);
  console.log(this.sItems);

  this.sItems.push(tsale);
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…) in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291187/cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-in-angular2)

Comment: Initialize `sItems` inline: `sItems: SaleProduct[] = [];`. You've declared it but you haven't initialized it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sItems: SaleProduct[];
```

This declares the object but doesn't initialize it and hence you get the error as the object is `undefined`.

Initialize it by the following code:

```
sItems: SaleProduct[] = [];
```